# Reduce white space on Manhattanplot (Package: qqman in R) between axis label and axis

Tags: r, plot, manhattan

i have ploted the Manhattan plot below via the package qqman in R. Unfortunatly, there is a huge white space between axis ticks and axis labels and also between axis labels and axis labs. Could someone offer any tip to reduce the white space?

This is my code:

```
manhattan(Table, chr="CHR", bp="BP", snp="SNP", p="P", suggestiveline = 4.66963295422, genomewideline = 5.97066294989, ylim = c(0, 12), cex = 1.0, cex.axis = 0.5)
```

[image: manhattanplot]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the spacing on the xaxis with `padj`.
This argument would go through the `...` argument to `axis()` function. Be aware that because these dots also go to other functions inside of `manhattan`, some warnings are triggered. THey should not concern you, however.

```
manhattan(gwasResults, padj = 1)
manhattan(gwasResults, padj = 0)
manhattan(gwasResults, padj = -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the place on the x axis is reduced now between the numbers and the ticks. But also the numbers on the y axis moved and are now above the ticks. There is also a second issue the word chromosome is still far away from the plot, so just the numbers moved but not the words. Do you have any solutions for that specific thing

Comment: I'd suggest to copy the source code of the function by typing `manhattan` without brackets in the console and change the function as you desire. you can not change everything just from the outside